# About robust regression

Tags: regression, sas, robust

I'm working on a robust regression analysis with `SAS`. I'm running a full model first.(using `PROC ROBUSTREG`). Then I'm excluding the variable with maximum Pr>ChiSq value. And then I'm running the model again. I'm repeating the process until Pr>ChiSq value is under 0.05 for all variables in the model. This is similar with backward elimination selection.
Is this approach correct?

Comment: are you confounding observations and variables?

Comment: no. I mean that I'm excluding **the variable** which is not statistically significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether backwards selection is appropriate has nothing to do with whether you used robust regression.

Model selection has been discussed many times here. The short answer is that backwards selection (and all automatic selection methods) has, at best, a mixed reputation. My own view is that these methods give wrong results and shouldn't be used. [This search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmodel-selection%5D%20automatic) will point you to a number of articles on the subject on this site.